# Remove Internet Security 2010 virus?

Tags: windows-xp, anti-virus, uninstall, internet-security

My system is infected with Internet Security 2010.

I can't even go to task manager or boot in safe mode. I also can't even run any antivirus programs.

Are there any solutions?

Answer (score 2):

I would strongly recommend that you backup your personal data and then clean install your OS. I would never trust a system after accidentally infecting it with a trojan. I would suggest:

1) Back up your data to some external drive

2) Aquire a live-cd virus scanner from some other computer, for example by using a friend's computer to download and burn the CD

3) Boot your computer with the live-Cd and make sure your external drive is attached. Scan the external drive, cleaning up any corrupted/infected data files found by the scanner

3a) remove the external drive until later

4) Find the install cd, or acquire a new install CD, and clean install. Reformat the hard disk, and clean install. Do not upgrade or anything like that. Clean install.

5) Reinstall any application you need

6) restore your files

I would also suggest taking this opportunity to evaluate what applications you are using and how you are organizing your data.

Comment: Wiping and reinstalling applications as needed is not a simple process. Why are you recommending a hammer when a few surgical strikes can solve this problem?

Comment: I strongly disagree that a few surgical strikes can remove a virus or trojan infection. Once the OS is compromised, you can't trust anything that the OS tells you. I am not the only one who holds this viewpoint.

Answer (score 2):

Install [**Malwarebyte's Anti-malware**](http://www.malwarebytes.org/), run a full scan, and clean all infected files.

If that doesn't work, install and run the scan in Safe Mode. After cleaning, you can install free antivirus like [**Avira Antivir**](http://free-av.org) or [**Microsoft Security Essentials**](http://www.microsoft.com/Security_Essentials/) to prevent future infections.

You can also get further help at the [**Malwarebyte's Anti-malware Forum**](http://www.malwarebytes.org/forums/)

Answer (score 2):

**[Remove Internet Security 2010 (Uninstall Guide)](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/virus-removal/remove-internet-security-2010)**

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/fr-fr/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) to terminate the processes IS2010.exe, 41.exe, winlogon86.exe and winupdate86.exe . Full removal instructions are [here](http://www.2-spyware.com/remove-internet-security-2010.html).

If that doesn't work for any reason, you may use a rescue live-CD virus scanner : I like best [Avira AntiVir Rescue System](http://www.free-av.com/en/tools/12/avira%5Fantivir%5Frescue%5Fsystem.html) because it gets updated several times a day and so the download CD is up-to-date. As a boot CD it's autonomous and doesn't work using your Windows XP system.

Once you succeed in erasing this virus, run antivirus scans by a couple of products. I recommend using at least [Malwarebytes' Anti-Malware](http://www.malwarebytes.org/mbam.php).

Answer (score 0):

You need to go into Safe Mode, then run a program called "RKill", then run MalwareBytes. I got this trojan on my computer over the weekend and successfully removed it after following the steps on this site: http://www.softsailor.com/how-to/13827-how-to-uninstall-remove-internet-security-2010-virus-removal-guide.html.

Answer (score 0):

Jeff Atwood has a [good article](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000888.html) about how to clean up a spyware infection. Following these steps should get you pretty close. Using some of the products recommnded by harrymc will also help you remove this virus.

Good luck, and hope this helps some.

Answer (score 0):

This thing about buying a particular new virus checker to cure the Internet Security 2010 virus is exactly what they want you to do, and is a complete waste of money. My system was hit by this horrible virus resulting in the “blue screen of death” and being deprived of access to any controls. What I could do, however, is reboot!

So I rebooted, held down Key F8, and got the boot options.

I chose “System Restore” option and turned the clock back by one week.

Although an error message appeared saying it had failed, it actually hadn’t! When I rebooted, the system was perfect again, and I hadn’t even lost any data – everything was right up to date, and I simply deleted the suspect file the virus came from.

Problem solved!